# How to implement Notification service (not using Activity) in Android

Tags: android, notificationmanager

I am implementing notification my app just example.

Service class file:

```
public class Services 
{
public void myNotify(Context context,String message)
   {
      Log.v("my notification method","from GetNotification class");
      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      Notification notification = new Notification(0,"A new notification", System.currentTimeMillis());
      // Hide the notification after its selected
      notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
      Log.v("services","11");
      //Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(""));
      Log.v("services","22");
      PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("")), 0);
      Log.v("services","33");
      notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,"Notification for you",message,activity);
      Log.v("services","44");
      notification.number += 1;
      Log.v("services","55");
      notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
      Log.v("services","66");
   }
}
```

AppActivity main class:

```
public class AndroidPlatformservices extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
 Services str= new Services();
 str.myNotify(this,"wrwtrerwetwttwretwrterwterw"); 
}
}
```

In log cat total file method executing:

```
06-16 22:09:11.472: VERBOSE/my notification method(5128): from GetNotification class
06-16 22:09:11.472: VERBOSE/services(5128): 11
06-16 22:09:11.472: VERBOSE/services(5128): 22
06-16 22:09:11.483: VERBOSE/services(5128): 33
06-16 22:09:11.493: VERBOSE/services(5128): 44
06-16 22:09:11.503: VERBOSE/services(5128): 55
06-16 22:09:11.513: VERBOSE/services(5128): 66
```

What is the problem?

Comment: While you are wondering what is the problem ... I am wondering what is the questions? Does this not do what you expect? If not what is the error? Are you trying to make an Android Service or are you using a class that's just called Service?

Comment: hi greg problem program executing successfully not display status bar notification ie problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a proper ressource id for the icon in the Notification constructor, 0 won't work.